# Talend Open Studio exporting job as a webservice and calling it without URL parameters

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, talend

I am working with Talend for the first time. I have created a Talend Job and exported it as an AXIS webservice war file. I have deployed this on a tomcat container.

Now in order to call this webservice, by passing values for the context parameters, I need to build a URL with the values set on it.

For example the URL might look similar to this:

```
http://localhost:10080/StandardParcellor_0.1/services/StandardParcellor?method=runJob&arg1=--context_param%20DeliveryParcelMetadataFileLocation=C:\dev\temp\DMS\b2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123\a2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123\metadata.xml&arg2=--context_param%20WorkingPath=C:\dev\temp&arg3=--context_param%20DeliveryParcelID=db604807-8606-4107-8d3e-aff08c95db1c&arg4=--context_param%20PackageWorkingFolder=C:\dev\temp\DMS\b2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123\a2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123
```

If you notice my URL is awfully long and there are characters in the URL that need to be encoded properly. This is causing me a lot of grief. Even if it works now, it could break later on either on the basis of the length of the URL or encoding that I am doing right.

I was wondering and hoping that since this is a web service call, especially a SOAP call, can't we set these parameters in an XML? Create a soap envelope and pass this into the webservice? Probably even generate classes that I can use from the WSDL and call the webservice the right way, as opposed to this horrible looking URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN order to call Talend web service, you can construct a post XML and send it out as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tal="http://talend.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tal:args>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <tal:item>--context_param DeliveryParcelMetadataFileLocation=C:/dev/temp/DMS/b2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123/a2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123/metadata.xml</tal:item>
         <tal:item>--context_param WorkingPath=C:/dev/temp</tal:item>
         <tal:item>--context_param DeliveryParcelID=3a91335b-4789-48c5-b6dc-8fac9c20a8d0</tal:item>
         <tal:item>--context_param PackageWorkingFolder=C:/dev/temp/DMS/b2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123/a2345678-2234-1234-1234-123456789123</tal:item>
      </tal:args>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The above seems to work. Was hoping someone could confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to have the generated war be callable with a prettier URL as far as I know.

An alternative option is to stick a web server in front of it with redirects that build the necessary URL.

Comment: hey.. after I raised the question, I was digging about and I think I found a way. I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

credit to: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html#zz-2.5
and
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7423

say you have a job named x and exported as x_0.1.war.

put the following html file in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/yourapp directory

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Ingest </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please enter values for the job</h1>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/x_0.1/services/x" method="get">
<p>Method:<br><input name="method" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" value="runJob"></p>
<p>arg1:<br><input name="arg1" type="text" size="60" maxlength="1000" value="--context_param context1=blahblahblah"></p>

<INPUT type="submit" name="submitJob" value="Start Job">  

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

arg1, arg2, arg3 etc will be your parameters passed as context variables